# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.create at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.wa

Tags: java, selenium, automation, automated-tests, testng

**Problem:** I am a beginner with selenium and automation testing and I am writing a selenium script using java, TestNG, and maven. When I write everything in one class, all works fine, but I want to have a package for all objects, a package for tests, and Base Class with the main setting. The project will contain a class for every page from the website and a class for all tests.
**When I try to modify something appear another error is from the constructor in BaseClass and I have no idea why
The base class is this:**

**What I tried**

```
public BaseClass(WebDriver driver) {           
    this.driver = driver; 
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}
```

or `PagegeFactory.initElements(new AjaxElementLocatorFactory(driver, TimeoutValue), this);` and didn't work.

```java
package com.selenium.Base;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.*;
import page_objects.AnalizesiPreturi;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class BaseClass  {


    public WebDriver driver;
    protected static AnalizesiPreturi baseClass;

    public BaseClass(WebDriver driver) {  }

    public BaseClass() {    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.driver.chrome", "C://SeleniumWebdrivers//chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        //implicit wait
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
       driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

        //launch URL
        driver.get("http://googl.com/");

        //scroll
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,500)", "");

        //WebDriverWailt for all objects located by class name
        WebDriverWait wbd = new WebDriverWait(driver, 1000);
        wbd.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.className("AnalizesiPreturi")));
    }
    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown(){
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

Page objects class is this from another package

```java
package page_objects;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.Page;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import com.selenium.Base.BaseClass;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class AnalizesiPreturi extends BaseClass {
    public AnalizesiPreturi(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    @FindBy(css = "#onetrust-accept-btn-handler")
    WebElement cookie;
    @FindBy(css = "#footable_501 > tbody > tr.ninja_table_row_0.nt_row_id_77 > td.ninja_column_1.ninja_clmn_nm_pret.footable-last-visible")
    WebElement plus1Button;
    @FindBy(css = "#footable_501 > tbody > tr.ninja_table_row_1.nt_row_id_78 > td.ninja_column_1.ninja_clmn_nm_pret.footable-last-visible")
    WebElement plus2Button;
    @FindBy(css = "#calculator > div.body > div.products > div.innerProducts > div > div.right")
    WebElement minusButton;
    @FindBy(css = "#show-hide > div.hide")
    WebElement closeButton;
    @FindBy(css = "#footable_501 > thead > tr.footable-filtering > th > form > div > div > input")
    WebElement search;
    @FindBy(css = "#footable_501 > thead > tr.footable-filtering > th > form > div > div > div > button.btn.btn-primary")
    WebElement findButton;

    @Test
    public AnalizesiPreturi addAnalises(){
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        cookie.click();
        plus1Button.click();
        plus2Button.click();
        closeButton.click();
        return null;
    }
}
```

And the last one is the Test package

```java
package Test;
import com.selenium.Base.BaseClass;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import page_objects.AnalizesiPreturi;
import page_objects.Centers;

public class TestsPage extends BaseClass {
    public TestsPage(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
    }
    public WebDriver getDriverInstance() {
        return driver;
    }

    @Test
    public void TestAnalises()throws Exception{
        //Tests
        driver.get("");
        AnalizesiPreturi analise = new AnalizesiPreturi(driver);
        analise.addAnalises();
    }
    public void TestCenters(){
        Centers centre = new Centers(driver);
        centre.checkCenters();
    }
}
```

The below is the received exception:

```
org.testng.TestNGException: 
An error occurred while instantiating class Test.TestsPage. Check to make sure it can be instantiated
    at org.testng.internal.InstanceCreator.createInstanceUsingObjectFactory(InstanceCreator.java:134)
    at org.testng.internal.InstanceCreator.createInstance(InstanceCreator.java:79)
    at org.testng.internal.objects.SimpleObjectDispenser.dispense(SimpleObjectDispenser.java:25)
    at org.testng.internal.objects.GuiceBasedObjectDispenser.dispense(GuiceBasedObjectDispenser.java:30)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:112)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:165)
    at org.testng.TestClass.getInstances(TestClass.java:122)
    at org.testng.TestClass.initTestClassesAndInstances(TestClass.java:102)
    at org.testng.TestClass.init(TestClass.java:94)
    at org.testng.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.java:59)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:463)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:339)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:292)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:183)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$DefaultTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:596)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:173)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:107)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1300)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1276)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1125)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:109)
```

OR

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.create(Ljava/util/concurrent/ExecutorService;)Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/SimpleTimeLimiter; at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.<init>(UrlChecker.java:62) at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:197)
```

Comment: Since you have mentioned that you are receiving an exception, please post the stack trace of the exception as part of the question.

Comment: @ Gautham M I added all the details in the description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a default constructor for `TestsPage`. (Not just for the base class)
TestNG tries to create an object of the test class by the following methods:

Loops all constructors:

1. Checks if any constructor is defined with `@Parameters`
2. Check if any constructor annotated with `@Factory`.

If there are no such constructors then:

3. At last it checks to create the test class using a default constructor.

So currently your code fails the above three criteria. Hence the exception.

Try adding a default constructor and it would work.

```java
public TestsPage() {

}
```

Comment: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.create(Ljava/util/concurrent/ExecutorService;)Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/SimpleTimeLimiter;

 at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.<init>(UrlChecker.java:62)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:197)

Comment: I do public class TestsPage extends BaseClass {
    public TestsPage(){
        super();
    }

Comment: @Ariana- this exception is not related to testng. Also you haven't mentioned the full stack trace for the above exception

Comment: Yes, I know that is not generated by TestNG, but this error appears after constructor modification.

Comment: @Ariana- it is a different issue. Update the question with the full stacktrace